# Install python third party modules from terminal in mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I am trying to install pandas on mac. I use this command in terminal:
`pip install pandas`. I get `Requirement already satisfied`. But in pycharm I can not import pandas.

My python version in terminal is `3.9.13` and pycharm python version is `3.10`.

**If the problem is because of different python versions, how can I fix it?** Thanks

Comment: PyCharm is using virtual environment for each project.  , you will see Run, Debug, Python Packages (Bottom left corner  of the IDE), click on python packages  (search it and install)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using VENV.
Go to the project dir and type in the below commands:

```
python3.10 -m venv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

Now go to [pycharm settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) and make it use the python sdk from the venv dir. That should solve the issue.

Or you can open the terminal inside pycharm and then do a `pip install pandas` over there. That should solve the issue as well.

Comment: installing from the terminal in pycharm solved the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check what python interpeter your python project is using.
Pycharm, generally, sets up a virtual env (isolated python environment) in project directory. You can see Python version in right bottom corner in PyCharm. If you click it a dropdown will show up, with choice of interpreters. If you then go to "Interpreter Settings" you will see some more information.

As for installing packages, you can try go to your project directory and enter pycharm's virtual env (if it exists):

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then try

```
pip install pandas
```

As for bash shell, you can check which executable you are using with use of 'which' command.

```
which pip
```

If it displays something like that:

```
> /home/user/myproject/venv/bin/pip
```

it uses virtualenv pip.